# zindex issue with overlapping divs

Tags: html, overlapping

On a site I'm working on I have a two divs. One is a div with content and an image, the content is in front of the image. The other div is a background image with a black gradient meant to overlap the former div - the image, but not the content. This works fine until the first site breakpoint. Also, it works perfectly on one page but not on another, which is really confusing since I can't see any difference between the two.

Working - http://www.osullivans-pubs.com/draft/?page_id=18
Not working - http://www.osullivans-pubs.com/draft/

I've also attached images of the method working, and not working (at the smaller width).

I'm kind of stumped at to what might be wrong. The element that should be in front has the .hero-unit class. Its zindex is higher than the background image div's.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="controls">
    <a href="#right" data-liquidslider-ref="slider-id"><div class="button_circle_small right">&gt;</div></a>
    <a href="#left" data-liquidslider-ref="slider-id"><div class="button_circle_small left">&lt;</div></a>
</div>
```

use the above code just before

```
<div id="back_gradient"></div>
```

Comment: *EDIT - Sorry, I thought that had fixed it. But still no luck. Why would moving that markup make a difference, out of interest?

Comment: can you tell me what is the actual problem...is with slider arrow or any thing other

Comment: No it's not with the slider arrows. It's the section.hero-unit element. It should appear in front of the #back_gradient element. It does at full width, but not at the more narrow width, as seen in the attached screenshots.

Comment: @user1473358 i think its working fine what have to you do is you want the image will show on full width please make it to understand what you really want because there is no different between the both link

Comment: There is a difference, as seen in the screenshots. To see the difference open this link http://www.osullivans-pubs.com/draft/ , resize your browser window to about ipad size (about 800px or so) then refresh. The hero unit content appears behind the gradient.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add a z-index in liquid-slider.css file below is the code...

```
.liquid-slider-wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto;
   clear: both;
   overflow: auto;
   position: relative;
   width: 1110px !important;
   z-index: 20;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work as I need. I want the image to appear behind the gradient (and the section.hero-unit to appear in front) but with the zindex on the liquid slider over 10 the image appears in front of it. I'm really confused because it works fine at full width...

Comment: @user1473358 you have need to resize the back_gradient_big.png size according the diffrent media size..

Comment: I've already done so. It needs to overlap the image, but not the hero-unit. Resizing doesn't resolve this.